# Change date format for xAxis in nvd3 chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have a working multibar chart but i have not been able to change the date format.

In the json datastring the date reads as 2016-01-01, 2016-02-01 etc and I would like to have it read as Jan 16 on the x Axis.

Here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xpz526xo/6/

Here is what i tried to add to change the date but has no effect

`chart.xAxis
      .tickFormat(function(d) {
          return d3.time.format('%m %y')(new Date(d))
      });`

Apologies for the formatting of above code as i'm submitting on a mobile phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
var format = d3.time.format("%Y-%d-%m").parse;//needed to parse the string to date
var chart = nv.models.multiBarChart();
chart.xAxis
.tickFormat(function(d) {
  return d3.time.format('%m %y')(format(d)); 
});
```

You **MUST** define the xAxis/yAxis tick format before you draw it in the SVG *(that is the reason why you are not seeing the ticks formatted).*

working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/h3u7m630/)